# Spead syntax can't use in Typescript's class

Tags: typescript

TypeScript codes as below:

```
interface ChildrenPropsType {
  children: Array<TheElement<any>>
}
class TheElement<PropsType extends object> {
  props: PropsType & ChildrenPropsType;
  constructor(props: PropsType, children: ChildrenPropsType) {
    this.props = {
      children:children,
      ...props
    }
  }
}
```

> Error: TS2698:Spread types may only be created from object types.

How to fix this error?

---

```
tsc --version
Version 2.5.2
```

Comment: Spread currently is not supported with generics. You can workaround this by `...props as any`. [Related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is logged on github at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12759

One workaround would be to use `Object.assign()` directly - just remember that unlike the spread operator, `assign` modifies the first parameter - so always pass in an empty object:

```
interface ChildrenPropsType {
  children: Array<TheElement<any>>
}

class TheElement<PropsType> {
  props: PropsType & ChildrenPropsType;
  constructor(props: PropsType, children: ChildrenPropsType) {
    this.props = Object.assign(
        {},
        children,
        props
    );
  }
}
```

You might also need to polyfill `Object.assign` ([see browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;)).

Comment: I found I can use

    `this.props = {
      children ,
      ...<Object>props
    }`